# Write User Prompts Object Array to an JSON file format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to ask user certain prompts and collect the answers and write to a file in the following format. The keys with values would be the prompt question and answers. How do I store questions so that I can prompt them in the following format, then write to a file in the below format.

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "targets": {
    "MyApp": {
      "type": "application",
      "platform": "iOS",
      "deploymentTarget": "10.0",
      "sources": [
        "MyApp"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "CUSTOM_BUILD_SETTING": "my_value"
      },
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "target": "MyFramework"
        }
      ]
    },
    "MyFramework": {
      "type": "framework",
      "platform": "iOS",
      "sources": [
        "MyFramework"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For example - what is the name of the project, then collect the answer and map to the object and then write to file.

Comment: Start with the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: What have you tried so far ? (You will always be asked to show code)

Comment: don't worry!! I got that done.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I see this is simple JSON.

You should consider checking out these two functions:

- `JSON.parse(JSON)`
- `JSON.stringify(OBJECT)`

You `JSON.parse` to read text that is written in JSON and for example put it in a javascript variable and this variable will actually be an object.
You use `JSON.stringify` to convert a javascript object into a JSON format text.

That's explained really minimalist so consider just googling them out.

As a start consider using `JSON.parse('{ "name": "MyProject", "targets": { "MyApp": { "type": "application", "platform": "iOS", "deploymentTarget": "10.0", "sources": [ "MyApp" ], "settings": { "CUSTOM_BUILD_SETTING": "my_value" }, "dependencies": [ { "target": "MyFramework" } ] }, "MyFramework": { "type": "framework", "platform": "iOS", "sources": [ "MyFramework" ] } } }');` in the browser console.